# Excel vlookup adds sheet name as a cell value in a column

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am hopeless in Excel.

I am trying to combine several workbooks into a single new workbook using vlookup.  I believe that I have been able to do this, but I would like to have a column that places the name of the worksheet or the workbook that it pulled the row from.

If someone could please point me to a couple of references that I can look at for this I would be very thankful. I have attempted to look for a while but maybe I am not using a good search or not calling something by the right name.

I may not even be using the right tool within excel to join these multiple exports into a single workbook, and if any one has any other suggestions please point me toward something else I can read.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have any examples of Your trials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pull the worksheet name over with Vlookup but there is a workaround if you are able to put extra information in the original worksheets.

Add another column in the worksheets which concatenates the data you want to copy AND the name of the worksheet with a delimiter eg "@" in between them.

You can get the name of the sheet by using:

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-SEARCH("]",CELL("filename",A1)))
```

Then, when you VLookup the data, split the two pieces of data back into two columns on the target spreadsheet.